# Predicate function exists()

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, apache-age

Using the exists(expression) one can check for a property or path in a graph database. Looking at the example from the [docs](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html). You can use exists on properties as in `exists(n.surname)` and also on path. But from the example in the docs

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
 MATCH (n)
 WHERE exists(n)-[]-(name: 'Willem Defoe')
 RETURN n.full_name
$$) as (full_name agtype);
```

I’d expect the query to be

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
 MATCH (n)
 WHERE exists((n)-[]-(name: 'Willem Defoe')) 
 RETURN n.full_name 
$$) as (full_name agtype);
```

Since the syntax is `exists(path)`. Also since the expression `name: ‘Willem Defoe’` is a property I’d also expect that to be in curly braces thus the final query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
 MATCH (n)
 WHERE exists((n)-[]-({name: 'Willem Defoe'})) 
 RETURN n.full_name 
$$) as (full_name agtype);
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The query given in the documentation has a syntax error and the correct query as stated would be:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
MATCH (n)
WHERE exists((n)-[]-({name: 'Willem Defoe'})) 
RETURN n.full_name 
$$) as (full_name agtype);
```

You can raise an issue [here](https://github.com/apache/age-website/issues) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The correction that you have suggested is how it should be written. If you run the first query, it will produce an error that says:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3:  WHERE exists(n)-[]-(name: 'Willem Defoe')
                       ^
```

Similarly, the second query produces an error that says:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Willem Defoe'"
LINE 3:  WHERE exists((n)-[]-(name: 'Willem Defoe'))
                                    ^
```

Only the third query successfully parses and produces a proper output.

Answer (score -1):

You are absolutely correct, the documentation surely has syntax error and the query you suggested should be the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

You are right. EXISTS clause take argument property which is a vertex or a path so, in this example it should be like this

```sql
WHERE exists((n)-[]-({name: 'Willem Defoe'}))
```